# Gstreamer Python: EOS message not received?

Tags: python, gstreamer

I have a Python Deepstream app (based in Gstreamer) and I want it to end properly when pressed Ctrl+C.

My pipeline has the following elements:

```
source -> streammux -> tee -> nvinfer -> nvvideoconvert -> nvdosd -> filesink
                        |---> filesink
```

My main code is:

```
self.loop = GObject.MainLoop.new(None, False)
GLib.unix_signal_add(-100, 2, self.handle_sigint, None)
self.bus = self.gst_pipeline.get_bus()
self.bus.add_signal_watch()
self.bus.connect("message", self.bus_message_handler)
self.gst_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
self.loop.run()
```

The bus message handler function:

```
def bus_message_handler(self, bus, message: Gst.Message) -> bool:
    t = message.type
    logger.info(f"****************** Message received {t}")
    if t == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        logger.success("End of Stream")
        self.loop.quit()
    elif t == Gst.MessageType.WARNING:
        err, debug = message.parse_warning()
        logger.warning(f"{err}: {debug}")
    elif t == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        err, debug = message.parse_error()
        logger.error(f"{err}: {debug}")
        self.gst_error = f"{err}: {debug}"
        self.loop.quit()
    return True
```

And finally the sigint handler function:

```
def handle_sigint(self, user_data=None):
    logger.info("SIGINT detected. Sending EOS...")
    self.gst_pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())
    self.bus.timed_pop_filtered(Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE, Gst.MessageType.EOS)
```

The expected behaviour would be:

```
Run -> Ctrl+C pressed -> Print "SIGINT detected. Sending EOS..." -> Print "End of Stream"
```

But "End of Stream" is never printed out. Why the EOS message is not being received by the `bus_message_handler`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess, I haven't actually looked in the code for this detail, but I would assume that `timed_pop_filtered()` will take over all bus messages and either discard all messages or return the EOS in question. Since you didn't say it deadlocks/waits forever at the end I assume that `timed_pop_filtered()` returned the EOS correctly. Since `timed_pop_filtered()` will take away all messages your bus watch will not receive any more messages at this point.

So instead of grabbing away all the messages with `timed_pop_filtered()` you probably want to wait for a signal coming from your bus watch that is triggered whenever your EOS arrives there.

Comment: Yes... it looks like there was a problem with the `time_pop_filtered()`, removing that line makes it possible to receive the EOS message, but I didn't need to wait for a signal. Now I have to solve how can I make the bus check faster the messages, because I'm having a 10s delay. Thanks.

Comment: EOS comes when all data is processed. So it is more like.. where are the 10s latency in the pipeline coming from.